# Se debería hacer alguna excepciones a preguntas con múltiples preguntas pero que el propio usuario responde a su pregunta

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva, cierre-de-preguntas, pregunta-autorespondida

Resulta que he publicado una [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/529961/explicaci%c3%b3n-de-que-es-un-trigger-mysql) con varias preguntas, las cuales he auto respondido a mi mismo a mis preguntas y la duda que tengo es porque no se vuelven a permitir este tipos de preguntas de nuevos ya que hay usuarios que le gustan y le viene bien para futuros problemas, ya se que lo quitaron por el costo que tenia, pero por una pregunta no pasa nada, al menos es lo que pienso yo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si os fijáis tiene buena puntuación general y las que son malas seguramente se deba a las múltiples preguntas, por lo que yo os pregunto. ¿Por qué mejor no dejamos preguntas múltiples en caso que la responda el propio autor?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No quiero ganar reputación de hecho si hace falta para que se quede mi pregunta y respuesta en este sitio que cada vez que me voten no me den reputación lo aceptare siempre que este dentro de SOes.

Comment: si lo permitimos ... estaremos creando un duplicado dela documentacion que debe existir en cada sitio de cada lenguaje, librería o recurso informático ... WTH...

Comment: LA documentacion en el sitio debe ser muy mala para poder plantearse el permitir este tipo de preguntas por ejemplo MySQL... tiende a hacer documentacion basadas en migajas ... una pagina independiente para cada cosa ... por lo que no te deja ver términos o aspectos relacionados...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo como tengo poderes especiales, no me metí con tu pregunta, pero mi punto de vista es que tu pregunta, no es una pregunta.

No aborda un tema en particular, es una descripción de una funcionalidad de una base de datos. Esta misma descripción esta explicada por todos lados, hasta en mas profundidad. Es mas, la pregunta solo sirve para mysql, porque no todas las bases usan new y old de esa manera, y no todas las bases tienen la misma forma para definir un trigger, con lo cual ni siquiera es una pregunta canónica (que aborda a la mayoría de los lenguajes) si no a uno en particular. Con esto quiero decir que deberíamos escribir una pregunta de este estilo para cada motor de base de datos.

La misma descripción, existe en wikipedia, y hasta esta mejor detallada ahí.

Esta clase de no preguntas no aporta nada al sitio en particular. Podríamos escribir lo mismo para Store procedures, para funciones, o para cada palabra clave de cada lenguaje, y no es la funcionalidad del sitio. El sitio esta para responder problemas puntuales sobre programación, no para describir generalidades (aunque algunas preguntas sean sobre generalidades y sean validas).

No voy a desmerecer tu aporte, porque fue hecho desde un lugar con la mejor intención, pero siento que no suma nada. Seria mucho mejor si tuvieras un blog y escribieras esto mismo ahí. Acá, una pregunta así, no encaja con el formato.

A veces pensamos que aportar toda clase de conocimiento al sitio es lo que hay que hacer, pero no todo conocimiento debe, ni tiene porque estar aquí. Hay muchas cosas que se resuelven leyendo la documentación y otras que se resuelven buscando en google. Seguramente hay explicaciones completas sobre este tema en muchos lados, inclusive en el propio manual de mysql.

Comment: Me han recomendado que haga esto que he pero de una pregunta a una pregunta,  eso seria una solución?

Comment: @JavierG.Raya las preguntas se tratan caso a caso.. Yo en este caso, no lo veo ni como una ni como muchas. El problema es el mismo. Una pregunta que diga que es un trigger, no es una pregunta... es una definicion de una funcionalidad de una base de datos. Es como preguntar que es un IF... igual, sigo en mi posicion de no tomar partido (no cerrar, no comentar) por que tengo una posicion sentada, y no tiene porque ser la de todos. Si deje esta respuesta, ya que preguntaste...

Comment: Vale muchas gracias

Comment: Uy, no estoy de acuerdo con el planteamiento de la respuesta. Muchísimas de las cosas del día a día se resuelven buscando en google... y encontrando una publicación de Stack Overflow como primer resultado. Si solamente nos centramos en problemas muy concretos, estaremos siempre en el día de la marmota, resolviendo cosas muy parecidas porque estamos a un nivel demasiado detallado; por ello, hay muchos (yo me incluyo) que intentamos plantear preguntas más genéricas (_canónicas_ se les llama a veces) que cubran planteamientos más amplios y que puedan servir de documentación.

Comment: @fedorqui estoy de acuerdo, si la pregunta es totalmente canonica y completa.. pero en este caso, es una copia de la documentacion... por eso digo que yo por lo menos voy caso a caso...

Comment: @fedorqui si añado mas contenido a mi respuesta puede llegar a ser aceptada por la comunidad?

Comment: @JavierG.Raya habría que ver qué quieres explicar exactamente. Por ejemplo la pregunta [Disparadores vs Procedimientos Almacenados](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/73846/83) está muy bien, pues obtuvo respuestas bien detalladas. En tu caso, haces seis preguntas diferentes, que creo que darían para preguntas diferentes... si bien no todas ellas creo que vayan a ser tan útiles. Para mí, los puntos 5 y 6 son a los que más jugo puede sacarse, pero tampoco soy experto en el tema.

Comment: vale algo asi no : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/530211/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-cambiar-el-delimitador-por-defecto-en-mysql/530212#530212

Comment: @JavierG.Raya esa pregunta.. es un duplicado de esta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/286204/324 :(

Comment: Pues no la encontré ahora mismo la borro

Comment: @JavierG.Raya creo que la pregunta que formulaste se podría mantener, pero marcándola como duplicada de la que comenta gbianchi. Al fin y al cabo, el título de la que añadiste es mucho más representativo de la respuesta que la gente puede estar buscando.

Comment: vale entonces la añado @fedorqui

Comment: pero de todos modo en mi pregunta pregunto de que si se puede cambiar el delimitador por defecto en MySQL mientras que la otra pregunta que hay es sobre los trigger no sobre mysql Es necesario escribir DELIMITER para crear un trigger o para crear un procedimiento almacenado? @gbianchi

Comment: tu que opinas sobre ambas preguntas @fedorqui

Comment: @JavierG.Raya ¿a qué dos preguntas exactamente te refieres?

Comment: a esta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/530211/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-cambiar-el-delimitador-por-defecto-en-mysql/530212#530212 con esta dice que es duplicada https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/286204/324 @fedorqui

Answer (score 6):

StackOverflow es un sitio de **preguntas y respuestas orientado a resolver problemas**, el tipo de publicaciones que propones, bajo mi punto de vista, daría lugar a tener un sitio lleno de preguntas que no resuelven problemas, por lo que sería contenido prácticamente vacío.

Por otro lado, este tipo de preguntas poco específicas pueden provocar debates o malentendidos, lo que se traduce como más problemas.

Los usuarios que frecuentan StackOverflow no lo hacen buscando explicaciones concretas sobre temas amplios, para este propósito existen blogs, foros y otros sitios.

Comment: Completamente de acuerdo. Tanto contigo como con @gbianchi. Si permitimos este tipo de preguntas en SO cuando nos demos cuenta seremos un rincondelvago para programación donde vendrá todo el mundo a copiar y pegar la teoría de sus exámenes/trabajos. Aquí estamos para dar solución a problemas de programación, no para ayudar a la gente a buscar documentación, para eso está google! (Que lo usan bien poco algunos...)

Comment: si lo permitimos ... estaremos creando un duplicado dela documentacion que debe existir en cada sitio de cada lenguaje, librería o recurso informático ... WTH...

Comment: la documentacion oficial debería ser muy mala para llegar a permitirlo...